# How to rectify the following error for imagemagick on windows?

Tags: imagemagick-identify

I am getting the following error regarding imagemagick on windows:

> No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3489.
>   identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/554

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve the error?

Comment: Since it's giving you an empty string I guess it's failing to identify the image format in the file. What sort of file is it? Is it valid, i.e. will other software open it OK? If you have the unix command line `file`, e.g. from git bash, what does that identify this file as?

Comment: What was your exact ImageMagick command line? Did you provide the proper path the file? What version of ImageMagick? What was the file type?